# Field pack pixel and tonic strange php error

Tags: pixelandtonic, custom-fields, field-pack

This is when I am creating a fieldpack download channel field.

**Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: fieldpack/ft.fieldpack_pill.php**

Comment: I also get this error when viewing a pill custom field. It references line 132 for me. I'm using php 5.5.10, EE 2.7.3 and Field Pack 2.1.1.